# Something strange with pointer to video memory (0xB8000)

Tags: c, x86, osdev

I am writing an OS. I created pointer to video area in a RAM (0xb8000). But I have some problems with writing to to the screen.

To make it works (just writing letters) I have to write to memory with offset by 1 (like `mem[1] = char`, `mem[2] = colour`). And that worked fine. But when i need to implement scroll i got to copy from one part of memory to another. And here i got problems. I could not get an char from memory. Also this offset seems very strange but it doesn't work without it.

```c
void main() {
    volatile unsigned char* mem = 0xB8000;
    mem[0] = 'X';
    mem[1] = 0xf0; // black on white
    mem[2] = 'Z';
    mem[3] = 0xf0; // black on white
    mem[4] = mem[2]; // this line delete all prev letters from display (like shift them out of screen)
    mem[4] = 0xf0;
}
```

When I launch it without line `mem[4] = mem[2];` it works as it should. But with this line i got very strange result without all prev letters (X and Z)

These are the kinds of results I am seeing when it doesn't work:

[image]

This is what happens when I print `X` by itself. It appears to work:

[image]

`mem[2] = 'Z'` causes different colour of `X`. And further modification (like `mem[4] = 'Z'`) delete all these chars from screen

Comment: The duplicate is regarding the generation of code for one architecture but running the code in another. I believe the observed output in this question is likely because you compiled the code as 64-bit and then ran it in 32-bit protected mode. 64-bit code can't run properly in 32-bit code. It may appear to run but it will do unusual things. In OS development it usually manifests itself in an observable way when writing to the display. The screen anomalies you are seeing are very indicative of that. The other question has an answer with some solutions.

Answer (score 2):

As outlined in [this article](https://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_To_Screen), text mode memory takes two bytes for every character on the screen. The first one is the ASCII code byte, the other the attribute byte.

If you're trying to print "XZZ" on the screen, your code should look like :

```
void main()
{
  volatile unsigned char* mem = 0xB8000;
  mem[0] = 'X';
  mem[1] = 0xf0; // black on white
  mem[2] = 'Z';
  mem[3] = 0xf0; // black on white
  mem[4] = mem[2];
  mem[5] = 0xf0; // black on white
}
```

Of course, for it to work, you need to make sure you're compiling in 32-bits, like @@MichaelPetch suggested in the comments.

Comment: Video memory is read/write

Comment: Oh, I think it will be better with screenshots (https://paste.pics/89c80bcf5f07fd8ffedb46928fe98cee) and (https://paste.pics/14bbe5603eef27931321bcc342f2c5a7) you can see that mem[2] = 'Z' causes different color of X. And further modification (like mem[4] = 'Z') delete all these chars from screen

Comment: Thanks @MichaelPetch!

Comment: @nishima For each character on screen, you need to write two bytes. If you write only at 0 and 2, you can't know what will happen on screen. Maybe it'll work, maybe not.

Comment: If you write just a character to mem[0] and mem[2] without changing the video attribute the characters will display but the attribute used will be whatever was associated that that screen cell previously.

Comment: With `volatile mem`, `mem[4] = 'Z'` is more efficient than `mem[4] = mem[2]`.  IDK why you'd want to force it to read back the store instead of just doing two stores of the same value.  Especially because VGA memory is often mapped UC or WC (uncacheable or uncacheable+write-combining), so I think store-forwarding wouldn't happen.  You probably *don't* need `volatile`, because the compiler can't prove that nothing else has a pointer to that memory.  But sure it doesn't hurt if you don't care about code-size.  (With some compilers `volatile` probably blocks store coalescing into a DWORD store)

Comment: @PeterCordes : In the question he mentions he was going to work on scrolling. I suspect that the `mem[4] = mem[2]` was an attempt to copy data in memory from one place to the other as an experiment towards creating proper scrolling functionality.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: For proper scrolling functionality; I'd want a buffer in RAM so that you can copy from RAM to VRAM (and avoid copying from VRAM to VRAM, and avoid reading from VRAM). Note that the buffer in RAM can be (and typically is) significantly larger - e.g. maybe enough for 1000 lines (instead of only 25 lines) so that later on the user can use (e.g.) "shift+page up" to see all the important stuff that scrolled off the top of the screen in a "too fast to read during boot" way. It's also a good step towards supporting graphics modes.